# Alias works but can't run the command manually

Tags: bash, shell, alias

```sh
alias git-repo="xdg-open '$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g' -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g')'"
```

This alias works, but when I try to run it by hand it doesn't:

```sh
xdg-open '$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g' -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g')'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use variable expressions in single quotation marks. Try this instead:

```bash
xdg-open $(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e "s/:/\//g" -e "s/ssh\/\/\///g" -e "s/git@/https:\/\//g")
```